# SearchCoreResult returns Regional Date Value

Tags: search, search-results, date-time, regional-settings

I got the following formate returned from "Write" in english:

```
<write>09/12/2012</write>
```

I parse that with the following line and return a german format: 12. Sep.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(write),1031, 'd. MMM.')"/>
```

If i now change the regional settings to german i get the following result in the SCR

```
<write>12.09.2012</write>
```

but the german format that comes back is 9. Dez (9.12.2012) ...

How can i fix that?

Comment: What is the unformatted date after changing the regional settings to german? This function relies on ISO8601 format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ.

Comment: As i wrote, the date changes from 09/12/2012 to 12.09.2012 -> Its already regionalformated and no raw iso

Comment: Okay I understand, try this solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010customization/thread/96ed2353-f9c2-41d4-82f5-eac8954d45bb

Comment: What a bullsh*t... Why does it only recognise english time format? It has '.''s .. How does it interpret 12.09.2012 to 12/09/2012 ?! WHY!? ... Well done MS .. What happens now if someone changes the format back to english and i do substring? I would have a wrong date again.. I dont wanna do this for every possible region.

Comment: Nice fix, please post your code, as the solution so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with recognising if time has dots.If so then just took the values of dd, mm and yyyy and rebuilded the string then ..

```
<xsl:variable name="date">
    <xsl:call-template name="TransformDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="String" select="write"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<b class="smalldate">
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($date),1031, 'd. MMM.')"/>
</b>

<xsl:template name="TransformDate">
    <xsl:param name="String"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($String, '.')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($String, 4,2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($String, 1,2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($String, 7,4)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$String"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Does something like "06. Nov." no matter if region was set to english, or german (and i guess all the other countries with dateformat dd.mm.yyyy). Now you can easily switch to another dateformat (thanks to ddwrt).